# split on each edge in an image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm new to open cv. what I want to do is splitting on every edge that I detected with canny.
can someone help me how can I do this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AFGn.png)

please check the image I point where I want to split with two red arrows.
split at the first position of the next edge i mean where i showed in the image.

Comment: sure, but split *what*?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz split at the first position of the next edge i mean where i showed in the image.am i said clear ?

Comment: not split *where*, that's clear so far, but split *what*, that is the question you should answer. you may think it's obvious but it's not. you haven't expressed what's in your head. perhaps use automatic translation. you seem to be struggling with a language barrier.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```py
# Import preprocessors
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
org = cv2.imread(dir+'/im.png')

# Make a copy from that image
im = org.copy()
imH, imW = im.shape[:2]

# Gray version of that image
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Remove red arrows
im[np.where(im < 130)] = 0
im[np.where(im >= 130)] = 255

# Keep a copy of image without arrow
org = im.copy()
org = cv2.cvtColor(org, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/out_1_no_arrow.png', im)

# Dim the horizontal lines
im = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (1, 11), 20)
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/out_2_dim.png', im)

# Remove the horizontal lines
im[np.where(im < 190)] = 0
im[np.where(im > 190)] = 255
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/out_3_ptrs.png', im)

# Find contours and sort them by position
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts.sort(key=lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[0], reverse=True)

# Find and save blocks
x2, i, off = imW, 0, imW/5
lastX=None
for cnt in cnts:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(org, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    if abs(x2-x)>=off:
        i += 1
        cv2.imwrite(dir+'/out_block_'+str(i)+".jpg", org[0:imH, x:x2])
        x2 = x
    lastX=x
i += 1
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/out_block_'+str(i)+".jpg", org[0:imH, 0:lastX])

# Save the processed images
cv2.imwrite(dir+'/out_4_cut_positions.png', org)
```

Removed Red Arrows from original image:

[image]

Blur to remove horizontal lines:

[image]

Remove horizontal lines and keep candidate places:

[image]

Show candidate locations on the original image:

[image]

Final result and isolated letters:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response,actually this is what i wanted,but your code gives me an error which is :    cv2.imwrite('out_block_' + str(i) + ".jpg", org[0:imH, 0:lastX]) (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite
i debuged your code and at the end of the for loop LastX become zero which raises this issue.

Comment: Moreover, could you please explain your code more? how did you find the right dimension for splitting?

Comment: Hello :) Please use the same original image that you attached (image with red arrows) for the initial test.
Comment wherever you have an error and try again.
Make sure the image input address is correct. Because I gave the address according to my computer folders.

Comment: Here's how the algorithm works: A simple idea is to find the vertical lines in the image and separate them. Some of these lines may form the beginning of an alphabet letter. Find lines that are at least one letter apart.

Comment: To understand the mechanism of this method, I suggest you comment on all the lines of code from the bottom, and then from the top, line by line, take the codes out of the comments and test the program :) This helps to better understand the code :)

Comment: Ok; You're welvcome :)